# Grails isAttached() and attach()

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Trying to use

```
if(!musician.style.isAttached()){
    musician.style.attach();
}
```

The code registers that isAttached returns false.
However when it tries to attach() it gives me an error saying

```
"object with the same identifier value was already associated with the  session"
```

Help me understand. If the identifier is already associated with the session, why does it not return TRUE for isAttached() to session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too where the theory didn't deliver as expected during runtime. My solution was something like `musician.style = Style.get(styleId)`, where you get your `styleId` from your `params` or where you remembered somewhere. This works correctly of course, but it is a database/cache call, which is bad if inside a loop.

Comment: this is the less than ideal solution I went with as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: I think **mohsenmadi**'s answer is most likely relevant to your issue - I had missed that `style` is an associated domain object.

It's hard to be specific without seeing more of your code, however my suspicion is that you may have duplicate objects with the same identifier, one of which is attached to your session and one is not (with is why `isAttached()` is returning false). I've seen this happen when doing lots of manual session management (implementing batch processing, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I couldn't  find a duplicate in the application yet so I used to mohsenmadi's solution as a patch for now.

Comment: Si there a way to see duplicates (one attached and one not) and remove them?

Answer (score 1):

All Entities in current session can be found in

```
grails.util.Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.sessionFactory.currentSession.persistenceContext.entitiesByKey
```